# Layout takes time to start

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView that I have created. But whenever I click on one of the list items it takes about 5 seconds to open. This is because I have about 90 views in that list item layout. These views are TextViews which I used to hold text for a particular chapter of a book.
Is there a way to reduce the delay without me deleting those views in the list item layout?

Comment: This is hard to answer without looking at the actual code. Are you actually using a `ListView`? Android's `ListView` is able to create elements on demand when the become visible. If this is still not enough, you might need some more tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html

There are some good ways to improve in your case, such as:

- Optimizing Layout Hierarchies
- Re-using Layouts with
- Loading Views On Demand

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Please use multiple fragments for each chapter . So that you can get then to one main screen as desired by the length of the chapter . Basically use the fragmentation technology because they are just like Iframes on a web page . Just like you see multiple web pages on a single web-page by Iframes , you can see each chapter from a different view using fragments .